# Removing something from a single li tag

Tags: html, css

So I've have a header `ul` tag list with 7 `li` tags, but I want to remove the css design from just one of the `li` tags.

It basically looks like this in CSS:

```css
#stuff ul li {
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
#stuff ul li:hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 1);
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="stuff">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li>
      <img src="pictures/logo.png">
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

The li tag with the picture has the hover and padding added to it as well, but that's not what I want. So I wonder if there is a way to remove these functions from the single li element?

Comment: Is your image always inside the fourth `li`?

Answer (score 0):

If its position is known, you can combine the `:nth-child` and `:not` selector

```css
#stuff ul li {
         margin-left:7px;
         margin-right:8px;
         float:left;
         display:block;
         font-size:24px;
         padding:25px;
         text-align:center;
    }

#stuff ul li:not(:nth-child(4)):hover {
     display:block;
     background-color:rgba(15,15,15,1);
     color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="stuff">
    <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><img src="pictures/logo.png"></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

If its position is unknown, add a class to the `li` that has the image and use the `:not` selector

```css
#stuff ul li {
         margin-left:7px;
         margin-right:8px;
         float:left;
         display:block;
         font-size:24px;
         padding:25px;
         text-align:center;
    }

#stuff ul li:not(.img):hover {
     display:block;
     background-color:rgba(15,15,15,1);
     color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="stuff">
    <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li class="img"><img src="pictures/logo.png"></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can try this

```
#stuff ul li:nth-child(4):hover 
 {
 background-color:transparent;

 }
```

Comment: but then what if the image is on the first or second bullet point?

Comment: yeah on that case the not over seems to work fine otherwise custom css might to write for that case

Answer (score 0):

It will be the simplest solution for you, just add new class to the li you need to exclude 
here i am adding 'noHover' class.

**HTML**

```
<div id="stuff">
    <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li class="noHover"><img src="pictures/logo.png"></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #stuff ul li {
         margin-left:7px;
         margin-right:8px;
         float:left;
         display:block;
         font-size:24px;
         padding:25px;
         text-align:center;
    }

#stuff ul li:hover {
     display:block;
     background-color:rgba(15,15,15,1);
     color:#FFFFFF;
}
.noHover:hover{ 
     display:block;
     background-color:inherit !important
 }
}
```

Have a nice day.